# Destroy de laravel no funciona 5.6

Tags: laravel, axios, vuejs, delete

No estoy pudiendo eliminar un registro de mi base de datos. los metodos POST, PUT, GET me funcionan osea pude hacer casi el CRUD. 
Intente de diferentes formas pero ninguna me funciona. No se que estoy haciendo mal.

Primero probé así

*Estoy usando axios*

```
eliminarPersona(id){
            console.log(id);
            const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
            customClass: {
                confirmButton: 'btn btn-danger mr-2 dr-btn-borderRadius',
                cancelButton: 'btn btn-success mr-2 dr-btn-borderRadius'
            },
            buttonsStyling: false
            })

            swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
            title: 'Estas Seguro?',
            text: "Vas a eliminar un cliente!",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Si, Eliminar!',
            cancelButtonText: 'No, Cancelar!',
            reverseButtons: true
            }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
            let me = this; 
            axios.delete('/cliente/eliminar',{
                'id':id
            }).then(function (response){
                me.listarPersona(1,'','nombre');
                Swal.fire({
                        position: 'center',
                        icon: 'success',
                        title:  'Eliminado! ',
                        text:'El Cliente fue ELIMINADO. ✔',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 1800
                        });  
            })
```

*ruta*

```
Route::get('/cliente',             'ClienteController@index');
Route::post('/cliente/registrar', 'ClienteController@store');
Route::put('/cliente/actualizar', 'ClienteController@update');
Route::delete('/cliente/eliminar', 'ClienteController@destroy');
```

*Mi controlador*

estas son las diferentes formas que probé

- Primer método

  ````
  {
      if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
      $persona = Persona::destroy($request->id);
   }```
  ````

de esta forma me devuelve 
  **data: ""
  status: 200
  statusText: "OK"**

pero no elimina, es como si no pasara nada

- Segunda forma

  ```
  {
      if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
      $persona = Persona::findOrFail($request->id);
      $persona->delete();
   }
  ```

  de esta forma me devuelve 
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  - Tercer Forma
    Lo único que hice fue que en vez de que sea un findOrFial solo find

  ```
  public function destroy(Request $request) 
  {
      if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
      $persona = Persona::find($request->id);
      $persona->delete();
   }
  ```

me devuelve esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi log de laravel me sale lo siguiente

**Correcion de LOG anteriormente copie uno viejo**

> local.ERROR: Call to a member function delete() on null
>   {"exception":"     [object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   Call to a member function delete() on null at C:\laragon\www\Danco-
>   Sis\app\Http\Controllers\ClienteController.php:68)

Probé de todo pero nada. No se que podría ser, capaz sea una pavada que no me doy cuenta

Comment: Verificaste si el id te llega al controller `$request->id`?

Comment: perdon, copie un log viejo este es el correcto

local.ERROR: Call to a member function delete() on null {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function delete() on null at C:\\laragon\\www\\Danco-Sis\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\ClienteController.php:68)

Comment: Considera editar tu pregunta y sustituir el otro mensaje de error por el actual, si te dice *on null* considero que no esta recibiendo el valor que pretendes que es el `id`, cuando ejecutas `dd($request->id);` que obtienes?

Comment: Intenta de la siguiente manera `axios.delete('/cliente/eliminar', { data: { id: id } });`

Comment: `dd($request->id)` me devuelve el id del cliente. y probé `axios.delete('/cliente/eliminar', { data: { id: id } })` y lo mismo no mas

Comment: Los errores que te da, te dice que no encuentra ese id, por eso el error 404 y el 500. Uno te redirige a un status de no encontrado y el otro te dice claramente que no puede eliminar un null. ¿Estás seguro que es id que envías existe en tu bases de datos?

Answer (score 2):

El primer consejo que te doy es que utilices el estandar rest. 
Por ejemplo, el update y el delete deben enviar por la url el id del recurso de que deseas eliminar, así que puedes modificar levemente el enrutado que tienes de la siguiente manera:

Esto es lo que tienes:

```
Route::get('/cliente',             'ClienteController@index');
Route::post('/cliente/registrar', 'ClienteController@store');
Route::put('/cliente/actualizar', 'ClienteController@update');
Route::delete('/cliente/eliminar', 'ClienteController@destroy');
```

Lo podrías modificar de la siguiente manera de 2 formas:

1. Modificar métodos put y delete:

---

```
Route::get('/cliente', 'ClienteController@index');

Route::post('/cliente/registrar', 'ClienteController@store');

Route::put('/cliente/actualizar/{id}', 'ClienteController@update');

Route::delete('/cliente/eliminar/{id}', 'ClienteController@destroy');
```

el parámetro adicional {id} indica que vas a recibir un parámetro llamado id en la url, desde el controlador lo puedes recibir de la siguiente manera:

```
function update(Request $request, $id){
    $cliente = Cliente::find($id);
    $cliente->fill($request->all());
    $cliente->save();
}

function destroy($id){
    $cliente = Cliente::find($id);
    $cliente->delete();
}
```

2. Esta solución es más elegante puesto que utilizas el Route::resource que te brinda laravel, este te ofrece las operaciones básicas crud:

   - si haces un petición POST a la api clients, irá por defecto al método store del controlador
   - si haces una petición GET a la api clients, irá por defecto al método index del controlador
   - si haces una petición GET a la api clients/{id} y le pasas el id por parámetro, irá por defecto al método show del controlador, este método recibe el id y devuelve el cliente que tenga ese id
   - si haces una petición PUT a la api clients/{id} es obligatorio que pases el id por parámetro para que vaya por defecto al método update del controlador
   - Si haces una petición DELETE a la api clients/{id} es obligatorio que pases el id por parámetro para que vaya por defecto al método destroy del controlador.

si quieres usarlo de esta manera debes modificar tu enrutado de la siguiente manera:

```
Route::resource('clients', 'ClienteController');
```

en tus controladores solo deberás modificar el método update y destroy tal como te especifiqué en la solución 1.